# Forward outgoing mails to another port on home PC then to VPS and send it through VPS port 25

Tags: sendmail, mail-server

Hi I recently noticed it seemed my home ISP had banned me from sending through port 25 (I could send mails when my mail server just launched though). I tried to telnet to services like smtp.gmail.com with port 25 and resulted in failing to connect. So I guess I'm banned now.

I have a VPS which supports port 25. When my port at home was not banned. For receiving mails, I use reverse proxies. It's like Gmail sends requests to my VPS on port 25 then it's forwarded to my home PC on port 25, and the server program on my home PC handles the rest. Mails arrive, everything is fine. And it still works well now.

Since I'd like to have mails sent to popular online services like Gmail, as far as I know I should have the outgoing port set fixed to 25 (in the server program I use there is no option provided to change outgoing port anyway, at least in web GUI). **I wonder for sending mails whether it's possible to, let's say, forward outgoing requests on my home PC to my VPS through a not banned port, and let the VPS send these requests through port 25 to Gmail for example. I hope someone could tell me what I should look into, or I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how to achieve this.**

To my opinion, this workflow might look like below:

`Home PC try to send through port 25` -> `Outgoing Port Changed to 12345` -> `Forwarded to VPS` -> `Sending through VPS port 25` -> `Arrives at smtp.gmail.com`

I'd like to not have a smtp server on my VPS (no matter how tiny it is) if possible. I'd like to have my VPS only handling the forwarding. Sorry for the bad language since I am not very familiar with networking. I hope I made my problems clear to you.

Comment: Not an answer to the question you asked (which INHO is a Rube Goldberg way of doing things). Id simply set up a VPN from your home mail server to your VPS, then set your home mail server to relay mail through that - no port-forwarding neccessary.  I put to you that sending email from your own VPS may not be a great idea for its delverability though - especially if you can't set reverse DNS.

Comment: @davidgo thanks a lot. I will look into it.

Comment: @davidgo sorry it seems it's hard to find an answer due to my little knowledge to networking. What does it mean by relay my mails through VPN? By mentioning relay I assume I should set up a smtp server on my VPS to handle it? I found an open-source one called Haraka.

Comment: What OS are you using on the home mail server and VPS?

Comment: @davidgo I'm using Debian